# Reading a java file from different project

Tags: java, file-io

I have two different java projects , and im trying to read one java file in another java file in different project.

eg: i have two projects project1 and project 2. They have packages named package1 and package2 correspondingly. I am trying to read a java file lets say JavaFile2.java which is in package 2 in JavaFile1.java which is in turn in package1 of project1.

I only know that i have to read package2.JavaFile2 , how do i achieve this ?

Need help Badly :(

Thanks

Comment: Reading means how to use JavaFile2 in JavaFile1 ?

Comment: You are not including important information - such as if you are packaging the package2 code to a jar-file accessible during run-time from package1. Also, I suspect you mean "java class" (the compiled class) instead of "java file" (the source code). Also, what is your IDE?

Comment: Thanks for replying. what exactly i am trying to do is , project1 is a java class library , which has some annotations and also custom annotation processor(written by me). and the java files in project2 are annotated with these annotations. I am creating jar file out of project1 and adding it to project2. But in the annotation processor i need to open the file JavaFile2.java and read the contents.I am unable to do it. Im using NETBeans IDE , and i want to read from .java file not .class file.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use either file path relative to project2 or, what seems to be safer option, use absolute file path when opening the file. Overall doing such kind of cross-reference between projects is not a very good idea as you will be tight to the relative location of the two projects.

Answer (score 0):

Iam unable to understand the reason why you want to do so.

However, in the runtime both project1 and project2 will not have .java files available in JVM

having said that, the only option is to include the /src folder in your project archive (jar/war/ear) and writing an adapter which provides the resource from archive is seemingly possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a dependency to the project1 which specifies that the project2 is also on the classpath. Since you haven't specified IDE or anything else, there's nothing I can do right now...

You may try Maven for dependency management
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/

Comment: Thanks for replying. what exactly i am trying to do is , project1 is a java class library , which has some annotations and also custom annotation processor(written by me). and the java files in project2 are annotated with these annotations. I am creating jar file out of project1 and adding it to project2. But in the annotation processor i need to open the file JavaFile2.java and read the contents.I am unable to do it. I am totally stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toExternalForm()` to get the location of current project and "navigate" to the other project.

But like said before...I do not understand why you need such cross-referencing.

Comment: Thanks for replying. what exactly i am trying to do is , project1 is a java class library , which has some annotations and also custom annotation processor(written by me). and the java files in project2 are annotated with these annotations. I am creating jar file out of project1 and adding it to project2. But in the annotation processor i need to open the file JavaFile2.java and read the contents.I am unable to do it. I am totally stuck.

Comment: Hi, if u can see the code in this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313818/custom-annotation-processor-for-tracing-program-execution , Class A is in another project and the annotation processor i am defining has to override the process method shown in the link. this annotation processor and the annotation trace(its only a marker annotation) are packaged into a jar and added to project containing Class A. Hope i am clear. Thanks